# Why does a specific line in my shell script ('docker exec') fail to run as a cron job?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, cron

Have been tearing my hair out… For set up background - I have a docker container running paperless-ng, and am trying to automate backups. I have rsync running, mirroring a folder onto my backup drive.

I have a short shell script at `/home/user/paperless-backup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh -i
# Paperless backup shell script

cd /home/user/paperless-ng 
docker-compose exec -T webserver document_exporter ../export
echo 'The paperless backup shell script job has run. Runtime:' >> /home/user/cron-test.txt
date >> /home/user/cron-test.txt
```

I included the following lines in my user cron job list using `crontab -e`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * /home/user/paperless-backup.sh
```

So:

- I know that the cron tab runs fine, because the output at `cron-test.txt` increments the date just fine.
- If I run `paperless-backup.sh` just as a bash script using `$ bash paperless-backup.sh` it executes as expected, and new files are backed up.

But when run as the cron job, it seems to just skip the line starting `docker-compose`…

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference in this case, but why `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Try redirecting stderr to a file so you can see if it gets an error.

Comment: Thanks! I did change it to ```#!/bin/bash``` just in case… I added a ```>> /home/user/cron.txt 2>&1``` to the end of my cron job and the output tells me ```/home/user/paperless-backup.sh: 5: docker-compose: not found```

Comment: You need to set `PATH` in the script so it can find `docker-compose`, or use the full path of the command.

Comment: Most environment variables are not set in the `cron` environment. Perhaps your script depends on some of them?

Comment: D'oh! So obvious now. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Also, why do you force your script to be **interactive**? IMO, this does not make sense in a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

As helpfully pointed out by @Barmar and @Ted Lyngmo, the `cron` environment didn't have the same `PATH` variables as my user, so just needed it explicitly setting out.

Added a line using `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/container` and seems all good now.